# Simple 2 bars Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, charts

I want to use the chart control.. I want to present two bars on it. One for the right answers and another for the total answers given by the user.

Thats my SQLDataSource:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllQuestionStatistics" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" SelectCommand=" DECLARE @TotalQuestions int;
DECLARE @CorrectQuestions int;

SELECT @CorrectQuestions = COUNT( WiningComment) 
    FROM Threads
    WHERE WiningComment IN (SELECT CommentsID
    FROM Comments
    WHERE  UsersID=@UserID)


    SELECT @TotalQuestions =  COUNT(CommentsID)
    FROM  Comments
    WHERE  UsersID=@UserID

Select @CorrectQuestions as 'WinningAnswers',
@TotalQuestions as 'TotalAnswers',

" onselecting="AllQuestionAskedDataSource_Selecting">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="TotalQuestions" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CorrectQuestions" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to presentTotalQuestions as one bar, and CorrectQuestions as another bar..How do I achieve so?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to make your query as one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalQuestions -- count all comments
 , SUM(CASE WHEN CommentId = WiningComment THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CorrectQuestions -- if comment = wining comment add 1 else 0
 , SUM(CASE WHEN CommentId = WiningComment THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) WrongQuestions -- if comment = wrong comment add 1 else 0
FROM  Comments -- get all comments for user in where clause
LEFT JOIN Threads ON Comments.ThreadId = Threads.Id -- join with the thread table
WHERE  UsersID=@UserID
```

Is this related with post [I need help with subtracting the results from two queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648496/i-need-help-with-subtracting-the-results-from-two-queries/6648761#6648761) ?